# How to read the null cell in NPOI

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I use NPOI to read excel file. If the cell is numeric, the code is

```
movie.YourRating = watchListSheet.GetRow(rowNumber).GetCell(newIMDBformat["Your Rating"], MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).NumericCellValue;
```

However, if the cell is empty, then it returns an exception:

```
"Can not get numerical value from text cell."
```

After change to NumericCellValue to StringCellValue, it is also returns an exception. I wonder what I should use to read the empty cell. The excel file is written by SetCellValue(). Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to create the excel file?  I tried what you did above reading a workbook that I created in Excel, and it worked fine: I did not get an exception and the numeric value returned was zero.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newcomer to npoi, but my impression is that you have to check the `CellType` and then read the appropriate  `NumericCellValue`, `StringCellValue`, `BooleanCellValue`, `ErrorCellValue`, or `CellFormula` according to the type returned.

For instance, if `cell.CellType == CellType.Numeric` then you get the cell value with `cell.NumericCellValue()`, and if `cell.CellType == CellType.String` then you get the cell value with `cell.StringCellValue()`. If `cell.CellType == CellType.Blank` then there is no value so you must not try to read one (or you will get an exception).